# unresolved token "extern "c" long"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, download, linker-errors

I'm trying to write a c++ downloader (learning purposes)

and this line:
`URLDownloadToFile(NULL, dwnld_URL.c_str(), savepath.c_str(), 0, NULL);`

is giving me a linker error

```
Error   LNK2028 unresolved token (0A0000D1) "extern "C" long __stdcall URLDownloadToFileA(struct IUnknown *,char const *,char const *,unsigned long,struct IBindStatusCallback *)" (?URLDownloadToFileA@@$$J220YGJPAUIUnknown@@PBD1KPAUIBindStatusCallback@@@Z) referenced in function "unsigned long __stdcall MainThread(struct HINSTANCE__ *)" (?MainThread@@$$FYGKPAUHINSTANCE__@@@Z)   projectname C:\Users\****\*****.obj 1
```

the same line of code seemed to work earlier and I don't get why its suddenly stoping the build.
Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet?

Comment: Have you linked with `Urlmon`?

Comment: have changed the library or external dependancies path?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the following code? If not, I suggest that you could add it. Beacause you should link `urlmon.lib` when you use `URLDownloadToFile`.

```
#include <urlmon.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")
```